# Can we guarantee comparing float with == is safe if the float contains integer value only?

Tags: java, android, floating-point, comparison, precision

I have some for loop which require some float local variables:

```
float price=0;
float weight=0;
int[] amountArray={2,5,3};
for(int i=0;i<=10;i++){
    int amount=0;
    if(i<amountArray.length){
        amount=amountArray[i];
    }
    //other codes for price and weight
}
```

I want the price and weight to be embedded in for loop as local variables so I change the i from int to float:

```
int[] amountArray={2,5,3};
for(float i=0,price=0,weight=0;i<=10;i++){
    int amount=0;
    if(i<amountArray.length){
        amount=amountArray[(int)i];
    }
    //other codes for price and weight
}
```

Does the modified version works identical to the original version? Since i contains integer value only, which can be represented by IEEE 754 standard correctly, and it does not depend on any hardware (especially in android), so I think comparing float with <, <= ,== and casting to int are not a problem in this case, am I correct?

Comment: Issues of precision aren't just integer-or-not-integer, but it also matters how big the integer gets.

Comment: *"I want the price and weight to be embedded in for loop as local variables"* This style is actually worse. Compact code is only good if it isn't dense. Squeezing a ton of garbage in to the same line just makes it hard to read. And the part where you have to cast `i` to access the array is just terrible. Really, just do it the first way.

Comment: Consider calculating "price" internally in terms of cents instead of dollars.  That way, you don't have any floating point at all. Then you can "divide by 100" before printing out the final price.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how big the integer is.  A `float` has 23 bits for the mantissa, and it's always assumed that the bit to the left of the mantissa is 1.  That means that any positive integer whose value can fit into 24 bits can be represented exactly.  But if an integer is larger than that, there won't be enough bits.

For a demonstration, try visiting http://www.adambeneschan.com/How-Does-Floating-Point-Work/showfloat.php?floatvalue=30000001&floattype=float, which shows that if you try to represent the number 30000001 as a `float`, it will actually have the value 30000000.  Obviously `==` isn't going to work on integers that are that high.

Comment: There are 23 stored fraction bits, plus one implied bit for normal numbers, total 24 bits, not 25.

Comment: @PatriciaShanahan Aaargh, forgot the sign bit.  Thanks for the correction.